# How can we proramatically generate vega grammar JSON from vega-lite plot?

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega, observablehq

I am able to get vega json grammar on local installation of nodejs with `vega-lite` and `vega-lite-api` installed through `npm` as follows:

```
vl = require('vega-lite') 
vla = require('vega-lite-api') 
data = require('vega-datasets') 

const df2 = data['movies.json']()

const plot = vla.markBar().data(df2).encode(
    vla.x().fieldQ('IMDB_Rating').bin(true),
    vla.y().count()
  )

vega_lite_json = plot.toObject();
vega_json = vl.compile(plot.toObject()).spec;
```

However I am unable to make it work in Observablehq.

I am not able to do last line: `vl.compile(...)`.
This is what I have did:

```
vegalite = require("@observablehq/vega-lite@0.2")
vegalite.compile(plot.toObject()).spec;
```

It says: `TypeError: vegalite.compile is not a function`
Here is [link to my observablehq notebook cell](https://observablehq.com/d/440df37a1f6c5e48#cell-65) executing `vegalie.compile(...)`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the vegalite compile option is located within the vl object, like this: `vl.vegalite.compile(...)`

Here's a notebook with the modified code: https://observablehq.com/@shan/untitled/6

Comment: Why when tried in vscode with npm packages, it works with `vl.compile(...)`, instead of `vl.vegalite.compile(...)`?